# Does devm_kzalloc give contiguous memory?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

After going through the man page on devm_kzalloc I see that devm_kzalloc is "**Managed kzalloc. Memory allocated with this function is automatically freed on driver detach. Like all other devres resources, guaranteed alignment is unsigned long long**".

I have also gone through the man page of kzalloc, but I still have a doubt whether the memory allocated is contiguous.

I am working on some porting work where I see that devm_kzalloc is ported to devm_kzalloc_contiguous.
Hence, I am trying to understand whether there is any need for contiguous memory.

Comment: Where does `devm_kzalloc_contiguous` come from? There is no such function in the mainline Linux kernel sources.

Comment: @IanAbbott Yes, that right there's no devm_kzalloc_contiguous in mainline Linux, I am involved in some porting work from Linux to <SOME OS>, where devm_kzalloc is getting mapped to devm_kzalloc_contiguous. And my intentions were to understand why contiguous.

Answer (score 1):

In the book "Linux Device Drivers, 3rd Edition by Greg Kroah-Hartman, Alessandro Rubini, Jonathan Corbet" it is written that memory allocated by kzalloc is "**contiguous in physical memory**".

Hence, I am assuming as the devm_kzalloc memory is managed by kzalloc, devm_kzalloc memory has to be contiguous.